# Member log in via API

Tags: silverstripe

I want to log a member into Silverstripe via curl request. For example: site.com/subdomain/login/authenticate?email=address&username=name&etc

Quick and dirty example controller action...

```
class RemoteLoginController extends Controller {
    public function authenticate($request) {
        $email = $request->getVar('email');
        ....

        if (($member = DataObject::get_one('Member', "Member.Email = '$email'"...))) {
            Debug::show($member);
            $member->logIn();
        }
    }
}
```

Debug::show($member) is returning my member, but $member->logIn() is not logging the member in. When I navigate to the home page of the site after making the call in my browser, I am not logged in as the member.

How do I log a member into Silverstripe via API?

Comment: You can't be logged in if you're not passing the cookie PHPSESSID with your test request using the browser. You are using two user agents here (curl, and a browser), which do not share their session information, so it is normal that you are seen as not logged in in the browser. Hit the homepage again, this time using curl, and make sure you're passing PHPSESSID as a cookie, which you should have received from your first call

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, for not being more clear, but while testing, all calls are being made via the browser. The PHPSESSID cookie is not being returned in the response. The only cookie being returned is the alc_enc cookie.

Comment: The PHPSESSID cookie will be returned by your first curl request. If you do curl -v http://mydomain.com and check what is being returned under < HTTP/1.1 200 OK, you should see a Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=xxxxx if your login was successful.

Comment: I'm seeing it now. I'll answer my question properly once I have my solution in place. Thanks for the help.

Comment: When I hit the url: http://mysite.com/silverstripe/controller/action?email=email_address&group=9 via curl, Silverstripe is not setting a PHPSESSID cookie. I used debug::show(Session::get_all()) to spit out the Session from my controller action and all it contains is the 'loggedInAs' session. There is no 'session_start_time' listed as when I hit the home page directly. I am confused because looking at debug_request, it seems like the Session should starts in Director::direct() which is in the trace.